# Execute .bat file on a remote windows server (Java App installed on linux machine)

Tags: java, linux, windows, batch-file

I have a Java web application installed on a Linux machine.

My objective is to programmatically (integrated in my Java app), execute a .bat file located on a remote Windows Server machine (with credential).

If the remote machine would have been a Linux machine, I would have used the jsch library, but the difficulty is that the remote machine is Windows.

Answer (score 0):

SSH on windows is an option... if this can be used in your case I would consider it.

I've done this before and had a script execute based on a job from the Linux box which would SSH to the windows server, then execute the script there.

See more here-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/tutorials/ssh

Comment: I will check if its possible to install openssh on a windows server 2003

Comment: If not, another option (which can be messy) is to have a job on the windows side checking for the existence of a file, and running a script if it's there, and getting the file there via FTP.

Comment: I will implement a schedule task, in order to transfer the folder content periodically. Thank you for your advises